# How to package a shell script in a pip package

Tags: python, pip

I have a generic shell script used in all of the modules.

All of the modules install a common pip called `common`.
The script is something like this

```
common
   utils
     scripts
       build
         generic_build.sh
```

I've saw there is a way to install python script by adding to `setup.py` using the `scripts` or the `console_scripts` arguments. but `sh` files seems to be ignored. meaning they don't end up in the installed package.

Any ideas?

Comment: `sh` scripts are not ignored when adding them in the `scripts` list. Clearly, your issue lies somewhere else. Consider [creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks, worked. submit as an answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 20):

Shell scripts can be bundled in a distribution by adding them to the `scripts` list as if they were python scripts. Example:

```
# bash_scripts/spam.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo Running "$0"
```

A simple setup script for packaging the `spam.sh`:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='spam',
    scripts=['bash_scripts/spam.sh']
)
```

Building both source and binary dists includes the `spam.sh`:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel | grep spam.sh
copying bash_scripts/spam.sh -> build/scripts-3.6
copying build/scripts-3.6/spam.sh -> build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel/spam-0.0.0.data/scripts
changing mode of build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel/spam-0.0.0.data/scripts/spam.sh to 755
adding 'spam-0.0.0.data/scripts/spam.sh'

$ python setup.py sdist | grep spam.sh
copying bash_scripts/spam.sh -> spam-0.0.0/bash_scripts
```

After installation, check the shell script is included:

```
$ pip install dist/spam-0.0.0.tar.gz
...
$ pip show -f spam
Name: spam
Version: 0.0.0
Summary: UNKNOWN
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /data/gentoo64/home/u0_a82/.local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
Files:
  ../../../bin/spam.sh
  spam-0.0.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  spam-0.0.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
  spam-0.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
  spam-0.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
  spam-0.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
  spam-0.0.0.dist-info/metadata.json
  spam-0.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
```

Comment: On my end there is nothing return under `Files:` , what should I do ?

Comment: Thanks @hoefling, that's super close to what I'm looking for! However the project I'm working on uses a `setup.cfg` file, and I didn't find the equivalent trick for this type of file. Is it possible to execute a bash script from a .cfg file?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you configure your setup.py file.
Try adding it as a resource or other type of dependency

```
 data_files=[('.',['INFO.txt']),
            ('additionalstuff',['additionalstuff/moredata.txt'])]
```